# eps cmyk color matplotlib output

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.2, eps, cmyk

I need to output my plots in EPS with the CMYK color space. Unfortunately this particular format is requested by the journal I am submitting my work to!

[This discussion](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/CMYK-images-td16339.html) was the only one I could find that has addressed the issue but it is more than 2 years old. I was hoping there might be some updates fixing the problem by now.

All my programming is in Python3 and so far I have been saving my plots in PDF which had no problem. But now that I want to plot EPS there is a problem. For example the code bellow prints the simple plot in .png and .pdf but the .eps output is totally blank!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X=[1,2,3]
Y=[4,5,6]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(X,Y)

fig.savefig('test.eps')
fig.savefig('test.pdf')
fig.savefig('test.png')
```

So I have two questions:

1. How can I fix the eps output?
2. How can I set the eps output color space to CMYK?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is newer (current) discussion: [link](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/CMYK-td40352.html)

Comment: Thanks, The discussion is new and it seems it has no solution yet! I guess I will just try to plot my final plots with Tikz/PGF for the journal. Does anyone have any idea why the eps output format isn't working?

Comment: With Python 3.3 and MPL 1.2 I also get empty PS/EPS, but with Python 2.7 I get correct output. Maybe it's a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too have the same problem. One workaround I have found is to save plots as `.svg` and then use a program like [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/%20Inkscape) to convert to eps. I used to be able to save in `.eps` without any issues and then lost the ability after an update.

**Update** I was able to solve this problem for my specific setup by changing a few lines in my `.matplotlibrc`, so I will post the relevant lines here in the hope that it may be helpful to you as well. Note this requires that you have `xpdf` and `ghostscript` already installed.

For me the important one was

```
##Saving Figures
ps.usedistiller : xpdf
```

But I also have

```
path.simplify : True 
savefig.format : eps
```

Now I am able to save directly to `.eps` and include them in LaTeX'ed journal articles...